# SSIS Script Component - Changing target .net version keeps reverting

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Hoping you guys can help :)

Using VS2015 with currently latest version of SSDT.
Have a script component and am trying to change the Target framework to 4.5.1  (from the default 4.5 - not sure where the default is gotten from)
Have followed the instructions [here](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.za/2012/05/changing-net-framework-version-in-ssis.html) - slightly modified for VS2015

The problem is that every time I set it and save, it reverts back to 4.5.
**Have also tried to set it backwards to 4.0 - same story.**

Have tried saving and closing down project and Vsta editor in all combinations to no avail and suspect that this might be an environmental issue.

Any ideas?

TIA

Edit: I've since tried the exact same thing on another machine and it works perfectly, so it does indeed seem to be an environmental issues.

Comment: @BHouse have you actually read my reply to the only proposed answer? Are you just looking for places to type comments?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you targeting?

Comment: Did you figure out what was different in your development environment that was causing this error? I'm having the same issue where my target framework reverts back to 4.5 and the references I added from NuGet for MySQL are lost. I don't have another machine to use to test this from. The only answer below isn't helpful because the SSIS project doesn't have a target framework and changing the script task target framework doesn't hold when re-opening the script.

Comment: @Brandon, sorry no.

Comment: If the TargetServerVersion is 2017 it forces it to 4.5 and will overwrite the changes made. I was trying to use a MySQL integration that I ended up finding an alternate solution for (I think by using a different library but I don't recall now).

Comment: @Brandon - if I recall correctly, the target version set was 2016

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do, when you are creating a project, make sure to choose Target framework to 4.5.1. Kindly refer to this [Cannot change Target Framework on Several Projects From v4.0 to V4.5 or 4.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316795/cannot-change-target-framework-on-several-projects-from-v4-0-to-v4-5-or-4-5-1)
.

Since you mentioned about environment issue, you need to verify that .net framework 4.5.1 and above were installed in your environment. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but unfortunately that doesn't work. I can do the exact same thing on 2 different machines - on one it works as expected and the other not.