# Version compatibility issue in SQL Server and SSIS Packages

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, business-intelligence

Currently in my machine visual studio community version 2017 version 15.9.3 has been installed and in server Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) has installed.

The issue is once I build the solution with available version and deploy it to server it gives following errors

[image: error]

even if i rebuild the ssis packages using old VS version and deploy it in server, still shows same error,

seems SSIDB keep tracking some meta data related to latest version deployment ispac.
still trying to figure it out the cause for this.
Initially what I want to do is using older version of VS ,need to deploy the ispac SSIS packages.

Thanks.

Comment: Open the package in a *new* version of Visual Studio or SQL Server Data Tools (a [free standalone product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) now) and upgrade it. If the old package targets .NET 2.0 it won't run in current .NET versions that work with .NET 4.0 without recompilation

Comment: changed to .net 4.0, 4.5 as well, same result.

Comment: But i tried by deploying to SSMS V17.3 then it works, but when it comes to V17.4 it doesn't . even if the version compatibility it has to be worked on v17.4 right?

Comment: SSMS is a databases client application, it can't be used to develop SSIS packages. It's *SSDT* you need. It's current version is [15.8.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017#ssdt-for-vs-2017-standalone-installer)

Comment: We have to degrade earlier versions and try this out until the proper compatibility. I had to uninstall visual studio and SSDT, after new installation issue got fixed, but  this is not ultimate solution, there has to be backward compatibility. `

Comment: event latest version of SSDT and VS doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue while upgrading from 2008/2012 to 2017. Somehow VS is not able to upgrade .NET version, even if you do so manually, it keeps coming back to the previous one. Your problem might be related to yet another issue though, but the last message in that validation outcome you pasted actually says about invalid script version and a failure while upgrading it automatically. If you only have a few of those scripts that are causing the problem, I would copy and paste the script to a brand new script component. If you have more, what helped us was this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33022362/4735777).

Comment: The script package fails because older SQL Server versions used the .NET 2.0 runtime while newer ones target .NET 4.x.  Opening the package in SSDT and recompiling (possibly manually changing the target runtime) is enough to sovle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue.  If you build SSIS packages in VS(SSDT) 2017 and they have script components/tasks, they will not work on SQL Server 2016.  Even though you set 2016 as the Target Version.

The only solution I know is to build your SSIS packages in VS(SSDT) 2015.

Comment: That's not correct. SSIS support is available as a [separate SSDT download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). VS and SSDT releases are perpetually out of sync though so you often need to repair SSDT after installing a VS 2017 update. Even the standalone SSDT installations are affected

Comment: I've been using VS 2017/SSDT since 2017, to target primarily 2014, 2017 and occasionally 2016. A single problem *always* occurs after an upgrade - SSDT tries to use a hard-coded older SQL UI dll than the one installed by VS. Eventually I installed SSDT as a standalone just for SSIS projects. That mess, and the lack of new features or any news for that matter over the last couple of years make me think that MS isn't that intererested in SSIS any more

Comment: The amount of bugs in VS 2017 is ridiculous. After some update I am no longer able to deploy the SSIS project from VS because it is unable to connect to the server. The newest update does not solve it and you need to reinstall everything to fix it... Insane.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Any tips on how to repair the SSDT installation if it is a VS 2017 workload?

Comment: @mdisibio SSIS is still only available through the standalone installer. Run the installer and click `Repair`. SSIS becomes an independent extension in VS 2019 but guess what ... Wizards and property pages crash, the Data Viewer doesn't show anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right. Confusing because you can have Workload for database projects but need standalone installer for SSIS or AS, etc. In the end I followed the steps outlined in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48402125/458354), using the `/layout` flag and forcing the download of components and running the repair one at a time. Additionally, a new SSIS package I created was targeting the wrong SQL Server version...don't know if that was new feature...I hadn't had to configure it before recent updates.